# VBA to Assign Named Range Reference

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to assign a named range's reference from VBA. I generate a string that I want to be the named range's reference.

Ultimately my code is much more complicated than what I will show here but this boils out the gist of my problem. I can assign the reference no problem, however, when I look at the named range in the names manager I notice that all of my quotes have been doubled. For instance ***I have a named range called "exampleName"*** and so I run the following:

```
Sub Example()
  Dim exampleStr As String

  exampleStr = "EVALUATE("" = "" &ADDRESS(5,8))"
  ThisWorkbook.Names("exampleName").RefersTo = exampleStr

End Sub
```

The code executes alright, but if I check under Name Manager I see:

[image: Named Range]

As you can see, under **Refers To** I've 'earned' an extra set of quotes around the equals sign. For my actual sub this becomes problematic as I have to iterate, augmenting **Refers To** on each iteration. Each time I iterate, all of my quotes are replicated. Within only a few turns I have way more quotes than intended.

Any input on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: [Name.RefersTo Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/name-refersto-property-excel): "Returns or sets the **formula** that the name is defined to refer to, in the language of the macro and in A1-style notation, **beginning with an equal sign**." Note **formula** and **beginning with an equal sign**.

Comment: @AxelRichter I'm not sure I understand what you're driving at. I expect the first equal sign, it's the additional quotation marks surrounding the _second_ equal sign that has me puzzled. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: If your `exampleStr ` shall be a **formula**, then it must be:  `exampleStr = "=EVALUATE("" = "" &ADDRESS(5,8))"`. Note the leading equal sign.

Comment: @AxelRichter Brilliant, thank you for the clarity!

Comment: You are welcome. But I doubt, that the formula will work. It should be `exampleStr = "=EVALUATE(""="" &ADDRESS(5,8))"` without spaces around the inner `=`.